# Month/Year SQL to correct format

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a textfield that users input the date using a modified jquery datepicker. The textfield has the Month and Year such as 'July 2011'

I need to run a query to search for results between July 1, 2011 and July 31, 2011. My date in the database is a smalldatetime, so I need my query to look like this:

```
select * from members where signupdate between 'july 1 2011' and 'july 31 2011'
```

How can I get the user inputted date of July 2011 converted to 'July 1 2011' and 'July 31 2011'?

**EDIT**

I'm only getting a 0 value from InvalidCount but I know I have one record in there as a test. Why isn't it being counted?

MY PROC:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Members m WHERE m.memberID = @pMemberID AND m.SignUpDate BETWEEN @pDate AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @pDate)-1) AS 'SignUpDate',
COALESCE(SUM(m.ValidCount), 0) AS ValidCount,
COALESCE(SUM(m.InvalidCount), 0) AS InvalidCount

FROM
dbo.Members m

INNER JOIN 
dbo.MemberStats ms ON m.MemberID = ms.MemberID  

WHERE 
m.SignUpdate BETWEEN @pDate AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @pDate)-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact syntax depends on the SQL Engine, but if you start with the 1st of the month, then add 1 month, and finally subtract 1 day; you get the end of the month.

(I'll assume MS SQL Server to match your C# tag)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  members
WHERE
  signupdate BETWEEN @param AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @param) - 1
```

Comment: this looks like it is working for me. added some code though. check my edits.

Comment: Your edit isn't really related to the question's title, I'd normally recommend a new question rather than an edit.  (For example; Include schema details, information about whether ValidCount and InvalidCount are nullable, etc, etc.  You may want SUM(COALESCE()) rather than COALESCE(SUM())), you may need an OUTER JOIN, there just isn't enough information to answer your edit at present.)

Answer (score 1):

If the between isn't *required*, you can use [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Untested example:

```
where DATEPART(yyyy, SignupDate) = 2011 and DATEPART(m, SignupDate) = 7
```

Comment: Or just `YEAR(SignupDate)` and `MONTH(SignupDate)`

Comment: Austin's approach is better because it avoid the confusion created by minutes. In TCC example, the whole july 31 day is ignored, as the time for it is '00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must convert the string representation to a valid DateTime struct object on the server. You can use `var date = DateTime.ParseExact("july 1 2011", "MMMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)` or `DateTime.TryParse`. Then you pass this into your SqlCommand as parameters. Never use strings when querying, especially when it comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

convert varchar to appropiate format you want and then compare
check the list of formats. Hope this helps dude.

[convert date](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)